adding to a column which is list of symbols and finding right datatype from meta information
I have a table which has 2 columns whose elements are list of symbols. I want to modify one of these columns to append a symbol to existing list of symbols, how can i do it ?
/Table with 2 columns containing list of symbols

tab:([] a:`A`B ;colList1:(`x`y`z;`p`q`r);colList2:(`x`y`z;`p`q`r));

/Gives me a list of symbols in colList2 but not in colList1, I need this for my task
 (exec colList1 from tab ) except'(exec colList2 from tab );

/Gives me a list of symbols in colList2 but not in colList1, I need this for my task
(exec colList2 from tab ) except'(exec colList1 from tab );

update missingincol2:(exec colList1 from tab ) except'(exec colList2 from tab ), missingincol1: (exec colList2 from tab ) except'(exec colList1 from tab ) from tab;

update colList1:colList1\:,`ooo from tab / This does not work as intended, I thought for each colList in it will join `ooo to it. But it looks like it create a new column x .


Moreover, when I do meta on a kdb table some of the columns which are list of list gets showed datatype as empty value. If there is a missing column which i want to add in my tickerplant log, how do i do this for a column which is list of list? Note that i do need to modify tp logs and so do not want to use dbmaint script etc. which would make changes directly on hdb level as I replay logs for my task.

Your final update statement should read:
q)update colList1:(colList1,\:`ooo)from tab
a colList1  colList2
--------------------
A x y z ooo x y z
B p q r ooo p q r

Commas indicate a new phrase in the statement so you need brackets to make it explicit that this indicates the join operator. Also the each-left (\:) iterator should be to the right of the operator you're modifying.

Your last example doesn't work because your syntax is wrong. Below is the corrected version
q)update colList1:(colList1,\:`ooo) from tab
a colList1  colList2
--------------------
A x y z ooo x y z
B p q r ooo p q r

You can also use each-both for this
q)update colList1:(colList1,'`a`b) from tab
a colList1 colList2
-------------------
A x y z a  x y z
B p q r b  p q r
q)update colList1:(colList1,'`a) from tab
a colList1 colList2
-------------------
A x y z a  x y z
B p q r a  p q r

I am not sure what you want to do with the TP log, the only way to modify the TP log is to replay it, modify the records and write it to a new TP log. I don't recommend modifying the same TP log as if you corrupt it, it will be lost for the day


Using , in qsql you must wrap it in ()
\: each-left should be to the right of your operator

q)update colList1:colList1(,)\:`ooo from tab
a colList1  colList2
--------------------
A x y z ooo x y z
B p q r ooo p q r

